# Onshore vs offshore curve construction

Tags: yield-curve, curve-fitting, multicurve, ndf

Can anyone guide me to links or literature regarding onshore vs offshore curve construction?
What kind of instruments do you use?

Take for CNH (offshore) (vs) CNY (onshore curves) for example:

For CNY onshore curves, when are the curves used for what products? Also, what are the instruments used under what collateral regime?

For CNH offshore curves, when are the curves used for what products? In the case of USD collateral, are {NDFs, XCCY(usd collateral)} used?

Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on the currency / market, but typically when some local currency has an offshore curve, and in a few cases even an offshore spot rate, due to capital controls, then you can build this curve from quotes for non-delivery forwards / non-delivery cross-currency swaps.

Comment: Can you make this question more specific and more detailed. I think it is a useful addition to the library but would benefit (and probably attract more answers) if it were more direct.

Comment: Sure let me do this.